# Collabnet subversion edge backup to network share is not possible

Tags: svn, collabnet

I'm running my collabnet under a VM (hyper-v), and I tried to set the backup destination directly to my NAS. Before the backup settings I already mapped the backup folder in the file manager with direct network path (map a network drive)  and with WEBDAV file sharing. So the OS (Win10) capable to connect  the NAS. But the Subversion is give me an error. " THE provided dump file parent directory not exist"
[subversion error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Phndj.png) 
is there any way to save the backup files directly to my NAS?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of reasons.

1. Drive mappings are not visible to Windows services. You should be able to use a UNC style network path like `\\Server\Share\Path` however.
2. By default the server is running using the Windows system service account and this account does not have any permission to any network resources. You can fix this problem by changing the service to run as a Domain user account that has permission to the network share you want to use.